# How to update data with GraphQL

Tags: mongodb, graphql

I am studying graphql.

I can retrieve data from my mongo database with queries, I can create data with mutations.

But how I can modify existing data?

I am a bit lost here...

I have to create a new mutation?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, every mutation describes a specific action that can be done to a bit of data. GraphQL is not like REST - it doesn't specify any standard CRUD-type actions.

When you are writing a mutation to update some data, you have two options. Let's explain them in the context of a todo item that has a `completed` status, and a `text` field:

1. Write mutations that represent semantic actions - `markTodoCompleted`, `updateTodoText`, etc.
2. Write a generic mutation that just sets any properties passed it, you could call it `updateTodo`.

I prefer the first approach, because it makes it more clear what the client is doing when it calls a certain mutation. In the second approach, you need to be careful to validate the values to be set to make sure someone can't set some invalid combination.

In short, you need to define your own mutations to update data.

Comment: hm but how? How can I edit one or all fields of some data object that, e.g. has a specific ID/key ?